# Initialise firebase-admin without using service account in noder/express server

Tags: node.js, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-admin

I am working on react web-app, which is served using a express server and we are using `ejs` to inject some initial data, like `cdnUrl` and other related info. Also I am using `firebase` remote config,to populate initial data before sending it to client, which can be used for feature toggle and other stuff.
So I am using `firebase-admin` sdk to poll the remote configuration, but to initialise firebase-admin we need to use service account which seems insecure.

Their docs says we can use `refreshToken` obtained from `OAuth 2.0` flow. But, is that method reliable for an app but not user to authenticate. And I have tried it but I am not getting `refreshToken` even if I everything went well, except app was not verified by google yet I continued.

So I want to initialise without using service account, also tried using `OAuth 2.0` but I am using all this first time. I am not sure which one is correct way.

I'm following this docs [add firebase to server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) , [modify remote config programmatically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/automate-rc)

P.S.
I can't share the code as it is in my office laptop.